# What is the chance that a PDF with compact support is concave?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functions, area

Relevant questions and answers, in chronological order:

- [When do equations represent the same curve?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375006/when-do-equations-represent-the-same-curve)
- [Find a smooth function with prescribed moments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935307/find-a-smooth-function-with-prescribed-moments)
- [Does a sequence of moments determine the function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002695/does-a-sequence-of-moments-determine-the-function)

All of the questions and answers are related to the
[Moment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem) .
The functions considered have *compact support* (hope this terminology is correct).
More specifically, the above Q & A list is related to the
[**Hausdorff moment problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem) ;
without loss of generality, the bounded interval is taken as $[0,1]$ .
As pointed out in the Wikipedia reference, the following integral sheds more light
on properties of the moments. Let $f(x)$ be real, integrable and positive with area
$\,m_0 = 1\,$ equal to one - in short: $f(x)$ resembles a Probability Density Function (PDF) - then:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) x^n (1-x)^k dx > 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left\{
\begin{array}{l} m_0 > 0 \; , \; m_1 > 0 \; , \; m_2 > 0 \\
m_0 > m_1 \; , \; m_2 > m_1 \\
m_0 - 2 m_1 + m_2 > 0 \end{array}\right.
$$
Attention will be restricted to the first few moments : $m_1,m_2$ .
If we put $\;x = m_1/m_0=m_1\;$ and $\;y = m_2/m_0=m_2\;$ then it follows that all $(x,y)$
values are within the $\color{silver}{silver}$ triangle with vertices
$(0,0),(0,1/2),(1,1)$ , as shown in the picture at the bottom.
$$
y > 0 \quad ; \quad y < x \quad ; \quad y > 2 x - 1
$$
Schwarz' inequality gives rise to a somewhat more restrictive condition: all $(x,y)$
values are within the $\color{gray}{gray}$ area between a parabola and a straight line:
$$
y < x \quad ; \quad y > x^2 
$$
This is as far as I have been able to go with general considerations about moments.
But if someone knows better, I'm eager to learn about it.

### Special theories

Couldn't proceed with the general, so I've tried some special cases. Because I think it's better to be successful
with something special than to fail with anything general. This is the reason why I've
payed so much attention to extremely simple PDF-functions, sample functions namely that
are completely determined by their first few moments. Among these are:

- [**histograms**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002695/does-a-sequence-of-moments-determine-the-function/1030888#1030888)
  consisting of three blocks with the same width

Please **read** the reference, because the argumentation shall not repeated here.

[image]

The three moments $\,m_0,m_1,m_2\,$ are linear in the three function values
$f_0,f_1,f_2$ and vice versa. Meaning that there is a one-to-one mapping between
function space and moment space $\,(x=m_1/m_0,y=m_2/m_0)\,$ where $m_0 = 1$ .
The moment space of 3-histograms is in the picture below. If the only
requirement is that the histogram is just positive (and with area $= 1$) then
what we have is the $\color{blue}{blue\; triangle}$. If an additional requirement
is that the histogram is concave then we have the $\color{green}{green\; triangle}$
*as a proper part* of the blue one. Let's formulate this as follows.
Consider the
universe of all PDF 3-histograms, what then is the *chance* that such a histogram
is concave ? The answer must be the quotient of the areas of
the green and the blue triangle. With the above reference that is: $\,(4/243) / (1/27) = 4/9$ .
With other words: $\large 4/9$ of all histograms in our special universe are concave.

[image]

But this is indeed a very simple example. A couple of questions arise:

- In general, has an idea like this been launched before?
- If not in general, do there exist other special examples of PDF universes
  where the question "what is the chance that a PDF is concave" makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another example in the abovementioned
[**special answer**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002695/does-a-sequence-of-moments-determine-the-function/1030888#1030888)
which is less complete there and shall
be completed here.
Consider the *universe* of all PDF-like **parabolic** functions
at the interval $t \in [0,1]$ :
$$
p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2
$$
The following Q & A has been helpful with visualization of the parabolas:

- [Maximum of parabolas at interval $[0,1]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037969/maximum-of-parabolas-at-interval-0-1)

[image]

There is a linear relationship between the coefficients
of the parabola and the first few moments, via the Hilbert matrix and its inverse:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} m_0 \\ m_1 \\ m_2 \end{array} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\ 1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4 \\ 1/3 & 1/4 & 1/5 \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{array} \right] \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad
\left[ \begin{array}{c} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{array} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 9 & -36 & 30 \\ -36 & 192 & -180 \\ 30 & -180 & 180 \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} m_0 \\ m_1 \\ m_2 \end{array} \right]
$$
As usual, we define the coordinates in moment space as $\,x=m_1/m_0\,$ and $\,y=m_2/m_0\,$
with the area normed to one $\,m_0=1$ .
Let's start with demanding that the parabolas are positive at $[0,1]$ .
Which is e.g. the case if the discriminant is negative together with a positive leading coefficient:
$$\color{blue}{
\left. \begin{array}{l} a_1^2 - 4 a_2 a_0 < 0 \\ a_2 > 0 \end{array} \right\}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
152 x^2 - 300 x y + 150 y^2 - 42 x + 40 y + 3 < 0 \\
y - x + 1/6 > 0 \end{array} \right. }
$$
Note that what's up here is exactly (the inside of) the ellipse that was questioned about in:

- [Indefinite integral with sector of ellipse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047156/indefinite-integral-with-sector-of-ellipse)

with the line $y - x + 1/6 = 0$ tangent to it in $B=(1/2,1/3)$ .
This question and
its answers are a prerequisite for understanding what follows.
Another way for the parabola to be positive is that $\;p(0) > 0\;$ and $\;p'(0) > 0\;$ ,
or $\;p(1) > 0\;$ and $\;p'(1) < 0\;$ , again with positive $a_2$ :
$$ \color{red}{
\left. \begin{array}{l} a_0 > 0 \\ a_1 > 0 \\ a_2 > 0 \end{array} \right\}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
y - 6/5 x + 3/10 > 0 \\
y - 16/15 x + 1/5 < 0 \\
y - x + 1/6 > 0 \end{array} \right. }
$$
$$ \color{red}{
\left. \begin{array}{l} a_0+a_1+a_2 > 0 \\ 2a_2+a_1 < 0 \\ a_2 > 0 \end{array} \right\}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
y - 4/5 x + 1/10 > 0 \\
y - 14/15 x + 2/15 < 0 \\
y - x + 1/6 > 0 \end{array} \right. }
$$
At last we have the possibility that the parabola is **concave** and positive:
$$ \color{green}{
\left. \begin{array}{l} a_0 > 0 \\ a_0+a_1+a_2 > 0 \\ a_2 < 0 \end{array} \right\}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
y - 6/5 x + 3/10 > 0 \\
y - 4/5 x + 1/10 > 0 \\
y - x + 1/6 < 0 \end{array} \right. }
$$
Working out the data results in the "ellipse with a hat" geometry
[**as has been presented**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047156/indefinite-integral-with-sector-of-ellipse) before.

Now we are ready to answer the question: what is the probability that a parabolic PDF at $[0,1]$ is *concave* ?
The answer is the area of the $\color{green}{green}$ triangle in the picture below divided by the
area of the ellipse-with-a-hat as a whole (i.e. $\color{blue}{blue} + \color{red}{red} + \color{green}{green}$ ).
And the end result is:
$$
\frac{1/180}{\pi\sqrt{3}/180(1-1/3)+1/120+2/720+1/180} = \frac{1}{2\pi/\sqrt{3}+3}
\approx 15 \%
$$

[image]

If I am allowed to say something subjective: I find the
geometry associated with this very specific problem of
an astonishing beauty. It all fits so neatly together
that it's almost a miracle.